# Converting to doc file in ASP.NET Core app and attaching doc file to email

Tags: c#, asp.net, docx, doc

I am trying to convert some data I get from my database in my ASP.NET application. So far I came across a very straight forward framework to do that called DocX.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/

So according to its API I decided that the best way to implement my task would be to first make a documents and save it to server. Then import it from server as stream and attach it to email. But I a doubtfull.

So I go:

```
            var doc = DocX.Create("test.doc");
            string f = "sdcdscdsc";
            doc.InsertParagraph(f);
            doc.Save();
```

Two things happen here:

1) First I get an exception FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Packaging
2) Somehow... when I tried another framework for doing this DocumentCore (https://www.nuget.org/packages/sautinsoft.document/), I guess that installed a missing file and the Save() method started working and saving the file but the files where blank.

Honestly I would really appreciate on best practices to do this task. If anyone has come across similar task please share the methodology used.

The second part is a bit easier. I got the email part sorted but still got no idea how to attach the file. So far the code looks like this:

```
    private static void SendMail()
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = "Tester ";
        mailMessage.Body = "This is the message";


        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
        {
            UserName = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
            Password = "xxxxxxxxx"
        };

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Overall it in bits and pieces and I would really appreciate some sharing of experience. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should separate these into two questions. How to use DocX is a separate question from how to add an attachment to an email. But make sure you've sufficiently researched your problem before asking any questions. There's lots of examples of using the DocX library and attaching files to emails.

Comment: You don't do anything with your `f` variable in your first code example, so I'm not surprised you're looking at what appears to be an empty file as the result.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Actually the part 1 of the question just got solved. Apparently the whole story happened because I should have used DocXCore since I am using ASP.NET Core. So now tryring to attach this doc to email somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 - create doc with content

Had to use DocXCore for ASP.NET Core app.

```
     private void CreateDocument()
     {

        try
        {
            var doc = DocX.Create("mytest.docx");
            doc.InsertParagraph("Hello my new message");
            doc.Save();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        } 

    }
```

Part 2 - sending email

```
    private void SendMail()
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage("xxxxx@gmail.com", "yzolxxxxxotarev@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = "Tester ASP.NET Boat Inspector";
        mailMessage.Body = "This is the message";

        var contentPath = _env.ContentRootPath+@"\mytest.docx";

        Attachment data = new Attachment(contentPath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(data);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
        {
            UserName = "xxxxx@gmail.com",
            Password = "xxxxx"
        };


        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Works well.